# Ext 4 Issue with mouseover, mouseout and drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, mouseover, mouseout

The problem goes as following:
I have a menu, and I wanted it to hide and show the elemens as the mouse passes by, I got it with mouseover and mouseout events, but the thing is that I can't actually select an item of the dropdown menu because it fades, I was thinking it might be because of problems with dom, but I am not quite sure, any help is appreciated! Code goes as following:

```
var PanelMuestra = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    width    : 850 ,
    height   : 250,
    style    : 'margin-top:15px',
    bodyStyle: 'padding:10px',
    renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
    html     : fakeHTML,
    autoScroll: true
});
new PanelMuestra({
    title: 'Menu',
    tbar: [{
        xtype:'splitbutton',
        text: 'Nuevo aca',
        listeners : {
            mouseover : function() {
                console.log('Dentro del area');
                this.showMenu();
            },
            mouseout: function (b) {
                console.log('Fuera del area');
                b.hideMenu();
                //Ext.menu.Manager.hideAll();
            }


        },
        menu: [{text: 'Ejemplo boton 1'}]
    },'-',{
        xtype:'splitbutton',
        text: 'Relleno',
        menu: [{text: 'Cut Menu Item'}]
    },'-',{
        text: 'Relleno'
    },'-',{
        text: 'Relleno',
        menu: [{

            text: 'Cut Menu Item'

        }]
    },'-',{
        text: 'Relleno'
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not show and hid your menu with custom events. Dropdown menus are natively supported in ExtJS 4.

Here is an simple example of a button with a dropdown menu

```
Ext.define('Mb.view.TestMenu', {
    extend: 'Ext.button.Button',
    xtype: 'winbiz-menu',
    text: 'Test Menu',
    icon: Paths.img + 'page_white_winbiz.png',
    menu: {
        items: [{
            text: 'Export,
            itemId: 'export'
        },{
            text: Lang._('Test')
            itemId: 'test'
        }]
    }
});
```